# How to change a share folders name

Tags: server

I'm pretty new to ubuntu and I've been following lots of videos on YouTube however, I've come across a small problem. I've created a shared folder which works fine however I'm not happy with the name I've given it therefore I want to change the name.

HOW?

Comment: Can you open a terminal and paste the output of `ls -l /path_to_file`, replacing `/path_to_file` with the location of the file?

Comment: In Linux, "folders" are called directories. `sudo mv foo bar`. You will then need to configure your server to share a directory with the new name and location.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nautilus (File explorer)

Right-click that folder, select `Properties` then `Local network share`. Change the `Share name` and then click `Modify share` button.